# Discord python bot intents

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

If the solution is obvious, bare with me I haven't coded in more than 3 months. It seems to be an issue with intents, yes I tried searching up the issue. Hit a wall there (this happened when I tried to start up my dpy bot), [The error that I keep getting!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vdgMz.png)

````
import datetime
import traceback
import math
from datetime import datetime
from discord.ext.commands.cooldowns import BucketType
from discord.ext.commands import CommandOnCooldown, errors, clean_content, guild_only
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from random import choice, randint
from colorama import Fore
import keep_alive
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions, MissingPermissions, CheckFailure

keep_alive.keep_alive()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',
                      case_insensitive=True,
                      owner_ids=(Id place holder1, id placeholder2))
client.remove_command("help")
dev_ids = [id placeholder3]

def date(target, clock=True):
    """ Clock format using datetime.strftime() """
    if not clock:
        return target.strftime("%d %B %Y")
    return target.strftime("%d %B %Y, %H:%M")

def traceback_maker(err, advance: bool = True):
    _traceback = ''.join(traceback.format_tb(err.__traceback__))
    error = ('```py\n{1}{0}: {2}\n```').format(type(err).__name__, _traceback, err)
    return error if advance else f"{type(err).__name__}: {err}"
@client.command()
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("OMG!!! THIS IS A TEST !!!")
TOKEN = os.environ.get("TOKEN")

if TOKEN:
    print('Get real')
else:
    print("Looks like you're not the owner dumb dumb")

client.run(TOKEN)
````

Comment: what exactly is your question? what's the error? Read the docs to use intents ,https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intents.html

Comment: Sorry, made it more clear on what the issue is (I included an image of the error if that helps)

Answer (score 1):

If want to enable the default intents you can do so like this,

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True
intents.members = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!',
                      case_insensitive=True,
                      owner_ids=(Id place holder1, id placeholder2),
                      intents=intents
                      )
```

Note: Only enable the intents you will actually use.